# Segmentation Fault? No error I’ve seen…

Tags: python, button, error-handling, tkinter

I have this code:

```
from Tkinter import *
def get_info(key):
    pass#do more later
def create_new():
    create = Toplevel(root)
    create.title('Create A New Contact')
    Label(create, text='Name: ').grid(row=0, sticky=W+E)
    name = Entry(create, width=8).grid(row=1, sticky=W+E)
    Label(create, text='Address(ex. 1111 Main St, MyCity, Anystate 12345): ', wraplength=1).grid(row=2, sticky=W+E)
    address = Entry(create, width=8).grid(row=3, sticky=W+E)
def access():
    access_window = Toplevel(root)
    access_window.title("Access a Contact")
    Label(access_window, text="Enter a first name: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W+E)
    access_key = Entry(access_window, width=8).grid(row=1, sticky=W+E)
    Button(access_window, text="Submit", command=lambda: get_info(access_key.get('0.0', 'end-1c'))).grid(row=2, sticky=W+E)
root = Tk()
root.title('Address Book')
button1 = Button(root, text="Create New", command=create_new)
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button2 = Button(root, text="Access Person", command=access)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

There is a error with this line:

```
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

It gives me this error:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Why does this show up? What is a segmentation fault?

Comment: By the way, I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: What library are you using? I mean, where does the Button class come from?

Comment: My first line of code:

Comment: `from Tkinter import *`

Comment: What is in the `access` command?

Comment: Are you using threads in some other part of your program?

Comment: I will show the whole code.

Comment: @BryanOakley No, I have not used threads. I don’t even know what threads are!

Comment: Can you show the whole error, with stacktrace? Also, what OS are you running this on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Segmentation fault" is a very low-level error: it means that the operating system caught your program accessing a range of memory addresses that were not assigned to any actual memory.

If you were programming in C, this would indicate a bug in your code.  But you are programming in Python.  It is supposed to be *impossible* for anything you do in Python to trigger a segmentation fault.  The bug is not actually in your code!  The most likely cause of this problem is, believe it or not, a *hardware* fault: specifically, bad RAM.  Run the program over and over again at least 100 times; simultaneously, do something memory-intensive, like loading up lots of graphics-heavy web pages and then closing them all again, repeatedly.  Does it crash *every single time*?  If it doesn't, run [`memtest86+`](http://www.memtest.org/) and *leave it running* until it tells you which RAM stick is bad, then replace it.

Now, if it does crash every single time, you do have a software problem.  The next most likely scenario is that the Tkinter add-on is incompatible with the Python interpreter, the actual Tk widgets library, or both.  Uninstall and reinstall Tk and Tkinter from a known-good source (for instance, if you are running Linux, your distribution's package repository).  That should fix it.

Far less likely, but still possible, are outright bugs in Tkinter, Tk, one of the lower-level windowing libraries, or the Python interpreter.  Only consider this possibility if reinstalling known-good packages does not make the problem go away.

Comment: I think a hardware fault is unlikely. Tkinter is a very complicated library, and bugs are certainly bound to happen. I think that this should be reported to Python developers as a bug.

Comment: @JamesElegan It is very complicated, yes, but nonetheless both hardware problems and version skew are enormously more likely than an actual bug.

Comment: I think you are unreasonably assuming that developers will never make mistakes. I've seen admitted bugs crop up in important pieces of software (like my C compiler!). Python developers know there's a handful of ways to segfault the interpreter (many involving garbage collection or native modules) that will never be fixed.

Comment: @JamesElegan No, I am just assuming (from bitter experience) that version skew and hardware faults are *much more common*.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the program a couple times and the segmentation fault magically went away! The rest was still helpful, though.

Comment: @thecoder16 In case it wasn't clear: the segfault magically going away means *you have bad RAM*.  Find out which RAM stick is bad and replace it before it does something worse to you.

Comment: @Zack Okay! I will check.

Comment: The fact that the segfault magically went away does not necessarily mean bad RAM was at fault. Segfaults frequently occur in race conditions.